# MATLAB: script keeps displaying 100: and datetime at every loop iteration

Tags: matlab, date, for-loop, time

I have about 1000 lines of code within a for loop running in MATLAB (I'd rather not post the code here as its semi-confidential). For some reason within one of the for loops "100:08-Jun-2016 13:47:20" etc. or 100:datetime is displayed with every iteration. There's no "disp", no "datetime", no "100" in any of my code. I've searched through and can't find any line within that loop that does't have the semicolon silencer.

Any idea what might be causing this? (any way to figure this out without posting the code?)

Thanks

Comment: The reason is that you have a bug somewhere in your code.

Comment: Are you calling any external functions within your loop?

Comment: "I'm not a mind-reader" - my mom

Comment: Yes, like Suever said above, it is probably in a called function or script. You can use `depfun` to get a (usually long) list of all called functions.

Comment: Yea I had a feeling people wouldn't like this question..thought maybe there was some common something simple that caused this

Comment: It probably *is* something simple but nobody wants to sit here and guess at what's wrong with code they can't see.

Comment: would delete the question if i could

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In a specific line of your code, wherever and whatever that is, something is printing something to the standard output. You told us that there are no missing output-suppressing semicolons, and we trust you. Then the problem is that some function you're calling is printing that output against your will.

Just use the very fine [`evalc`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/evalc.html) function that does exactly this: suppresses output of whatever is executed with it. The simplest is to just put your entire function call inside it:

```
evalc('your_fancy_function_that_prints_stuff_in_the_loop(every,input,argument,here);');
```